# C# extract an embedded resource from assembly to a specific location in pc?

Tags: c#, winforms, export

How can I with button click export a file (file types: .jpg, .txt, .dll, ... etc) from my application resource code to a specific location on my computer (for example: C: \ drive)
I tried this code with button click:
*Main Code:*

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ApplicationName.Files.name.dll");
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("name.dll", FileMode.CreateNew);
        for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
            fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
        fileStream.Close();
```

But the application stoped and show me this error:
*Error Message:*

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

stream was null.
```

More Informations:

1) I upload a .dll file to my resources.

2) I changed from this file Build Action to = "Embedded Resource".

I tried with Clint's help below.
Images of my project now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW8cM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfcIr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tzGQ.png)

Comment: Is the name of your resource `ApplicationName.Files.name.dll`? If not, did you use the correct name in your actual code?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes. My application name is "ApplicationName" and the file i have upload in resources is "name".

Comment: If your assembly name is `ApplicationName` and the file name is `name.dll` and it's in a subfolder in the root directory called `Files`, then your code should work just fine. Make sure all of that is true.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Everything is like the "Main Code" up. But every time when i click the button then show me the error "stream was null". In folder was creared a file with name "name.dll" but the size of the file is 0kb.

Comment: hey @SwagHero, let me know if the solution below helps out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Scenario I (Your Scenario)*

- You have a project that has an embedded resource like (images,txt,etc)
- You want to extract this file from your assembly and transfer it to another   location

*Scenario II*

- You have Class Library project (dll) that has an embedded resource like (images,txt, etc)
- You load this dll in your main project and want to access the resources (image) in your dll

*Usage*

[image]

**Important: Before using the Code**

- **packages.config** is an **EmbeddedResource** (*Substitute it with the resource you are using*)
- `Namespace` of my project is **ConsoleApp** (*Substitute it with your namespace*)

---

**Main**

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

        ResourceManager.GetResourceInfo("packages.config");
        if (ResourceManager.resourceExists == false)
            return;

        //Loads packages.config in Bin/Debug
           ResourceManager.LoadResource("packages.config");

    }
```

**ResourceManager.cs**

```
    class ResourceManager
    {
      public static bool resourceExists { get; set; } = false;
      private static Stream resourceStream { get; set; }
      public static void GetResourceInfo(string fileNameWithExtension)
      {

          //Substitut this with your Project Name
        //Class Library Name AssistantLib >  Resources > AssistantLib.dll 
        const string pathToResource = "ConsoleApp.Folder1.Folder2";
        //The Dll that you want to Load
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        //var names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{pathToResource}.{fileNameWithExtension}");
        if (stream == null)
            return;

        resourceExists = true;

        resourceStream = stream;

       }

      public static void LoadResource(string newFileNameWithExtension)
      {
        if(File.Exists(newFileNameWithExtension))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
            return;
        }
        using (Stream s = File.Create(newFileNameWithExtension))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading file");
            resourceStream.CopyTo(s);
        }
      }
    }
```

**Output**

*Package.Config in output folder*

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207471/discussion-on-answer-by-clint-c-how-to-export-a-file-from-winforms-resource-cod).

Comment: Yes i did change it but is not worked. I removed the "name.dll" and i copy an other .dll file and then show me when i run it the "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\name.dll' is denied.'". How i can fix this?

Comment: @SwagHero, use the chat link above